# how to add multiple owners to LUIS app

Tags: azure-language-understanding

How can i add multiple owners to my LUIS app?

I can add multiple collaborator but as we know, collaborator have limited access.
I need to set multiple owners for my LUIS App. Is this feature available? any possibility to include such feature in next release?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available in LUIS, but it has been suggested as a feature in the past and is under discussion.

Comment: At least the ability to change the owner would also be a good feature, as only the owner can add collaborators

Comment: I completely agree with you :) we're evaluating making Role Management and Application Ownership much better. Unfortunately there currently are some blockers regarding these implementing new related features and feature requests...

Comment: @StevenG. Is there any update on this topic? I think it's still an important feature.